# Django Rest Framework Custom Authentication + return custom json

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using django 2.1 and python 3.6....I want to authenticate users using custom authentication and return token along with email and id after validating user.

***settinge.py***

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "users.views.authentication_backend.UserAuthenticationBackend",
)
```

***views.py***

```
class UserAuthenticationBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):

        validate_email(email)
        valid_email = True
        kwargs = {'email': email}

        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(**kwargs)

        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User does not exist.')

        if valid_email and user.check_password(password) and user.is_valid is True:

            return user

        elif valid_email and user.check_password(password) and user.is_valid is False:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Sorry your account is suspended temporarily,'
               )

        else:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Sorry, your email and password does not match.')
```

I want to return response as follow:

```
{'token':"", 'user': {'id': 1, 'email': 'admin@abc.com', 'is_active': True}}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Authentication class is not for ***returning responses***

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Token Authentication** or even **JSON Web Tokens(JWT)**
These can help you get a token as a response [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), 
[JSONWebToken](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication)

These can be helpful for your requirement,If you need any other additional help please do mention it!!!